# Layout components (drawer, toolbar, …) not working as component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-material

I'm using vue with [vue-material](https://vuematerial.io/).

I'm currently working to layout the main structure of my web app, using `md-app` as root for `md-[app-]drawer`, `md-[app-]toolbar` and `md-[app-]content`.

If I place these components directly in the `md-app` tag, they work. This looks like this:

```
<template>
  <div class="md-layout-row">
    <md-app>
      <md-drawer>
        <md-list>
          <md-list-item>
            <md-icon>people</md-icon>
            <span class="md-list-item-text">Foo</span>
          </md-list-item>

          <md-list-item>
            <md-icon>view_list</md-icon>
            <span class="md-list-item-text">Bar</span>
          </md-list-item>
        </md-list>
      </md-drawer>
    </md-app>
  </div>
</template>
```

But for design purpose I try to extract each of those inner parts (in this case the `md-drawer` tag) into own vue components.

### Problem

I have my `Drawer` Compnonent now, it looks like this:

```
<template>
  <md-drawer>
    <md-list>
      <md-list-item>
        <md-icon>people</md-icon>
        <span class="md-list-item-text">Foo</span>
      </md-list-item>

      <md-list-item>
        <md-icon>view_list</md-icon>
        <span class="md-list-item-text">Bar</span>
      </md-list-item>
    </md-list>
  </md-drawer>
</template>
```

.. and my `md-app` (after importing the component ofc) looks now like this:

```
<template>
  <div class="md-layout-row">
    <md-app>
      <MyDrawer />
    </md-app>
  </div>
</template>
```

But this doesn't render the drawer at all. Why is this? Does Vue wrap components additionally which may mess with the css of vue-material? Is there a way to bypass/fix this issue? .. or am I just using it the wrong way?

### Addition (Edit 1)

After some experiments I figured out that it works if surround `MyDrawer` tag with a `md-[app-]content` tag, but this doesn't result in the layout I'm looking for.

I guess `md-app` is looking for specifically these components, and because it doesn't know what to do with a `MyDrawer` tag it just ignores it? Although `MyDrawer` is essentially a `md-drawer` tag/component?

### Addition (Edit 2)

I've been reading about [DOM Template Parsing Caveats](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#DOM-Template-Parsing-Caveats), I figured this should work but I didn't have any success yet. I just declared a `<md-drawer is="MyDrawer" />` tag and removed the main wrapping `md-drawer` tag from `MyDrawer` component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. using the component incorrectly [doc](https://vuematerial.io/components/drawer)

> md-active - type = Boolean. Option used to trigger the drawer visibility. Should be used with the .sync modifier. Default =   false

example using for `Drawer`:

```
<md-drawer :md-active.sync="showNavigation">
  ...
</md-drawer>
```

2. `md-app` incorrect. see [Component-Naming-Conventions](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Component-Naming-Conventions)

example using for `md-app`:

```
<md-app>
  <my-drawer />
</md-app>
```

***note** *but before using look at the next answer*

3. Addition (Edit 1) - incorrect.

> Any other tag passed as a direct child of the md-app tag will be ignored. The component will only look for those three tags and choose the right placement for them. [Documentation](https://vuematerial.io/components/app)

example using for `md-app`:

```
<md-app md-waterfall md-mode="fixed-last">
  <md-app-toolbar class="md-large md-dense md-primary">
    <div class="md-toolbar-row">
      <div class="md-toolbar-section-start">
        <md-button class="md-icon-button" @click="menuVisible = !menuVisible">
          <md-icon>menu</md-icon>
        </md-button>
        <span class="md-title">My Title</span>
      </div>

      <div class="md-toolbar-section-end">
        <md-button class="md-icon-button">
          <md-icon>more_vert</md-icon>
        </md-button>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="md-toolbar-row">
      <md-tabs class="md-primary">
        <md-tab id="tab-home" md-label="Home"></md-tab>
        <md-tab id="tab-pages" md-label="Pages"></md-tab>
      </md-tabs>
    </div>
  </md-app-toolbar>

  <md-app-drawer :md-active.sync="menuVisible">
    <md-toolbar class="md-transparent" md-elevation="0">Navigation</md-toolbar>
    <md-list>
      <md-list-item>
        <md-icon>move_to_inbox</md-icon>
        <span class="md-list-item-text">Inbox</span>
      </md-list-item>
    </md-list>
  </md-app-drawer>

  <md-app-content>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Error quibusdam, non molestias et! Earum magnam, similique, quo recusandae placeat dicta asperiores modi sint ea repudiandae maxime? Quae non explicabo, neque.</p>
  </md-app-content>
</md-app>
```

4. Addition (Edit 2) - incorrect. `is` not matter in your case. [see using API](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#is) and [Component-Naming-Conventions](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Component-Naming-Conventions)

just use tag: `<md-drawer/>`

**UPDATE**

How to use custom `Drawer` in `md-app`.

`drawer` must be wrapped in `md-app-drawer`

Example

code:

```
<md-app-drawer :md-active.sync="menuVisible">
  <custom-drawer/>
</md-app-drawer>
```

[App](https://3xyx386q65.codesandbox.io/materialApp)

[Component](https://codesandbox.io/s/3xyx386q65?module=%2Fcomponents%2FmaterialApp%2FmaterialApp.vue&moduleview=1)

Comment: Thanks for your response! I'll get at it as soon as I have time and will get back to your response. Regarding your N°2; isn't `MyDrawer` a valid `PascalCased` component name? Regarding your N°3; so I need to directly use one of those 3 components? can't I wrap it in a custom singlefile component? Addtion #2 on my side is playing into this; if it only accept one of those 3, I figured I might say that it `is` indeed a drawer in this case

Comment: regarding your last sentence `just use tag xyz` .. that is exactly what I am trying to avoid by separating it into components. It's not like It wouldn't work if I have it all in one single file .. I'm having trouble separating those tags into single file components

Comment: Alright, I tested your example. It works like expected because you declare everything in-line. If I take your `md-app-toolbar` part, put it into a single file component template, include that component with `<my-toolbar />` and start the application, then it doesn't render anything. I'm not sure if I was clear in my question, but this is the whole problem.

Comment: many words...
example, special for you:

 [app](https://3xyx386q65.codesandbox.io/materialApp) 

and


[component](https://codesandbox.io/s/3xyx386q65?module=%2Fcomponents%2FmaterialApp%2FmaterialApp.vue&moduleview=1)

Comment: Ahh.. now we speak the same language ^^. Thank you. Update your answer to match the conclusion and I'll accept it as answer. the conclusion is that you have to keep an additional wrapping tag

Comment: I spoke too fast. having an additional wrapping tag does mess with the layout. I can bypass this by just having a wrapping tag and exclude the content into the component, but this only works for toolbar. the drawer does not work this way.

Comment: @TobiasWürth, I updated the answer. What prevented you from wrapping in `md-app-drawer`?

Comment: I managed to get it to work thanks to you, but I'm not a fan of this custom css, is it all that unusual to put those tags into custom components?